# Is it possible to control download speed using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt

Can we restrict `QNetworkAccessManager` from consuming whole bandwidth, by restricting the download speed, as we do see such options available with almost every download manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box. But have a look at the [Qt Torrent Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-torrent.html), especially the class `RateController` ([ratecontroller.h](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-torrent-ratecontroller-h.html) | [ratecontroller.cpp](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-torrent-ratecontroller-cpp.html)). This class does almost what you want by controlling not only one but a set of connections.

However, this rate controller is operating on `QTcpSockets` (to be exact on `PeerWireClients`), so you need to change the type of the "peers" to be `QIODevice`, which I hope isn't that hard, since `PeerWireClient` inherits from `QTcpSocket`, which itself inherits from `QIODevice`:

```
 // old
 void addSocket(PeerWireClient *socket);
 // new
 void addDevice(QIODevice *device);
```

(Note that the RateController from the Torrent example controlls both upload and download, but you only need to control the download rate. So you can remove unnecessary code.)

Then you need to make requests made by your `QNetworkAccessManager` use this rate controller. This can be done by reimplementing `QNetworkAccessManager` and overwriting (extending) the method `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest`, which will be called whenever a new request gets created. This method returns the `QNetworkReply*` (which inherits from `QIODevice*`) where the download will be read from, so telling the rate controller to control this device will limit the download rate:

```
QNetworkReply *MyNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(
                QNetworkAccessManager::Operation op,
                const QNetworkRequest &req,
                QIODevice *outgoingData)
{
    // original call to QNetworkAccessManager in order to get the reply
    QNetworkReply *reply = QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, req, outgoingData);

    // add this reply (which is a QIODevice*) to the rate controller
    rateController.addDevice(reply);

    return reply;
}
```

You will not have to subclass QNetworkAccessManager if you already know the pieces of code where you actually perform requests. The methods `get()` and `post()` return a `QNetworkReply*` which you can also just add to the rate controller. (But this way, you *manually* do this *outside* of the manager, which is doesn't fulfill the concept of information/implementation hiding, in this case the fact that downloads are rate-controlled.)

Comment: Actually, i won't be using QTcpSocket, is it possible with QNetworkAccessManager. I mean is something like this possible: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19134/

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot that. I adapted my answer. I hope this will work, since I've never done this. But this should do the trick. Note that you even need to go down to QIODevices since the QNetworkAccessManager doesn't tell you the socket but the target device. Limiting writing speed into the target device = limiting dowload speed.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that this will not work, since `outgoingData` is the data to be uploaded for HTTP POST requests. We need to put the reply itself instead of the outgoingData into the rate controller.

Comment: @leemes , Can I limit upload by adding outgoingData to RateController ? I mean, to limit both upload & download , reply and outgoingData need to be added to rateController ?

Comment: @Ashish Not sure, my answer is pretty old. But have a look at my source: the Qt torrent example, which controls *both* upload and download rate.

Comment: @Ashish I see no reason that it should not work. The rate controller works on the low-level QIODevice and connects to the QNetworkAccessManager. If you make a request of a HTTPS resource you do this by typically using the QNetworkAccessManager. Simply do this with this subclass and it should work.